# How can I return the odd indexed nodes of a singly linked list in a new singly linked list ?Assume index of the first node as 1

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, structure, singly-linked-list

When I run this code I am not getting an error message from the compiler but I can not return the new list. Am I writing down the code wrong in the MAIN part?

Input

```
10->20->30->40->50->60->70->80->90->100
```

Output must be

```
10->30->50->70->90
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct SinglyLinkedListItem
{
    int data;
    struct SinglyLinkedListItem*next;
}SLLI;


SLLI*OddNodes(SLLI*pHead)
{
    int counter =1;
    SLLI*pTemp=pHead;
    SLLI*pList=NULL;
    while(pTemp != NULL)
    {
        if(counter % 2 != 0)
        {
           if(pList==NULL)
           {
               pList=malloc(sizeof(SLLI));
               pList->data=pTemp->data;
               pList->next=NULL;
           }
           else
           {
               SLLI*pIter=pList;
               SLLI*pNew=malloc(sizeof(SLLI));
               pNew->data=pTemp->data;
               pNew->next=NULL;
               pIter->next=pNew;
               pIter=pIter->next;

           }
        }
        pTemp=pTemp->next;
        counter ++;
    }
    return pList;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I can not return the new list"? What happens when you run the code? What is supposed to happen? Also please take some time to read [ask] as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please try to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: Also, when creating a new list you need to create new nodes for the list as well. You can't reuse the nodes from the old list, it will destroy the old list.

Comment: @YTE 1008 Are even nodes removed from the source list and moved to the destination list?

Comment: I am pretty new on this platform and sorry for my bads firstly. I am not trying to solve the problem by removing even indexed nodes. I will also try it but not on this code.(What do you mean by "I can not return the new list"?) I mean that I can not see the output as first,third,fifth,... nodes of the current linked list on a new linked list when I run the code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are always changing the same object `pList->next`.

```
       else
       {
           pList->next=pTemp;
       }
```

And moreover the original list is not being changed. So the function has undefined behavior.

For starters you should pass the head of the original node by reference. Otherwise the function will deal with a copy of head and any changes of the copy will not influence on the original list.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the function can be implemented.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct SinglyLinkedListItem
{
    int data;
    struct SinglyLinkedListItem *next;
} SLLI;

SLLI * OddNodes( SLLI **pHead )
{
    int odd = 0;
    SLLI *pList = NULL;
    SLLI **pCurrent = &pList;

    while ( *pHead != NULL )
    {
        if ( odd ^= 1 )
        {
            *pCurrent = *pHead;
            *pHead = ( *pHead )->next;
            ( *pCurrent )->next = NULL;
            pCurrent = &( *pCurrent )->next;
        }
        else
        {
            pHead = &( *pHead )->next;
        }
    }

    return pList;
 }

 int insert( SLLI **pHead, int data )
 {
    SLLI *pCurrent = malloc( sizeof( SLLI ) );
    int success = pCurrent != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        pCurrent->data = data;
        pCurrent->next = *pHead;
        *pHead = pCurrent;
    }

    return success;
 }

 void out( SLLI *pHead )
 {
    for ( ; pHead != NULL; pHead = pHead->next )
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", pHead->data );
    }

    puts( "null" );
 }

int main(void) 
{
    const int N = 10;

    SLLI *pHead = NULL;

    for ( int i = N; i != 0; --i )
    {
        insert( &pHead, 10 * i );
    }

    out( pHead );

    SLLI *pSecondHead = OddNodes( &pHead );

    out( pHead );
    out( pSecondHead );

    return 0;
}
```

The function output is

```
10 -> 20 -> 30 -> 40 -> 50 -> 60 -> 70 -> 80 -> 90 -> 100 -> null
20 -> 40 -> 60 -> 80 -> 100 -> null
10 -> 30 -> 50 -> 70 -> 90 -> null
```

If you are not going to change the original list then the function can look simpler because in this case there is no need to pass the pointer pHead to the function by reference.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct SinglyLinkedListItem
{
    int data;
    struct SinglyLinkedListItem *next;
} SLLI;

SLLI * OddNodes( SLLI *pHead )
{
    int odd = 0;
    SLLI *pList = NULL;
    SLLI **pCurrent = &pList;

    for ( ; pHead != NULL; pHead = pHead->next )
    {
        if ( odd ^= 1 )
        {
            *pCurrent = malloc( sizeof( SLLI ) );
            ( *pCurrent )->data = pHead->data;
            ( *pCurrent )->next = NULL;
            pCurrent = &( *pCurrent )->next;
        }
    }

    return pList;
 }

 int insert( SLLI **pHead, int data )
 {
    SLLI *pCurrent = malloc( sizeof( SLLI ) );
    int success = pCurrent != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        pCurrent->data = data;
        pCurrent->next = *pHead;
        *pHead = pCurrent;
    }

    return success;
 }

 void out( SLLI *pHead )
 {
    for ( ; pHead != NULL; pHead = pHead->next )
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", pHead->data );
    }

    puts( "null" );
 }

int main(void) 
{
    const int N = 10;

    SLLI *pHead = NULL;

    for ( int i = N; i != 0; --i )
    {
        insert( &pHead, 10 * i );
    }

    out( pHead );

    SLLI *pSecondHead = OddNodes( pHead );

    out( pHead );
    out( pSecondHead );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
10 -> 20 -> 30 -> 40 -> 50 -> 60 -> 70 -> 80 -> 90 -> 100 -> null
10 -> 20 -> 30 -> 40 -> 50 -> 60 -> 70 -> 80 -> 90 -> 100 -> null
10 -> 30 -> 50 -> 70 -> 90 -> null
```

If you do not yest understand the work with pointers by reference then the function can look the following way

```
SLLI * OddNodes( SLLI *pHead )
{
    int odd = 0;
    SLLI *pList = NULL;


    for ( SLLI *pCurrent = pList; pHead != NULL; pHead = pHead->next )
    {
        if ( odd ^= 1 )
        {
            if ( pCurrent == NULL )
            {
                pList = malloc( sizeof( SLLI ) );
                pList->data = pHead->data;
                pList->next = NULL;
                pCurrent = pList;
            }
            else
            {
                pCurrent->next = malloc( sizeof( SLLI ) );
                pCurrent->next->data = pHead->data;
                pCurrent->next->next = NULL;
                pCurrent = pCurrent->next;
            }
        }
    }

    return pList;
}
```

Comment: I am sure you write the code without any simple error but it is not easy for me to understand or read the code.Because I do not have enough knowledge what is SLLI**pHead(I mean double ** )It is not possible to tell this to me on this platform, I am aware of this... So thanks for your help...I am going to understand this code one day...

Comment: @YTE1008 It is a one more level of indirection when you are passing not the original pointer pHead but a pointer to pHead. That is you are passing pHead by reference. As a result you can change pHead in the function.

Comment: Appreciated for your help @Vlad from Moscow

Comment: @YTE1008 Lets's assume you have a function void f( int x ); When you will pass an object to the function like f( my_x ); then the function will deal with a copy of my_x and will  be unable to change the original object. But if you will declare the function like void f( int *px ); When passing my_x by reference like f( &my_x ); then the function can change the original object my_x.

Comment: But what if I do not want to change the original linked list and just want to copy the odd indexed nodes into an another linked list and return this new linked list?

Comment: @YTE1008 In this case you have to allocate dynamically a copy of a node of the original list.

Comment: @YTE1008 It is a bad idea to change the code in the question after it was answered. This will confuse readers of the question and answers. The else statement in your function does not make sense because this declaration SLLI*pIter=pList; is a declaration of a local variable that will not be alive after executing the else statement.

Comment: I detected the same mistake but I can not solve this problem? Do you have any recommandation for me?

Comment: @YTE1008 Create a new question and return to this question your old code that was present initially.

Comment: I meaned how can I solve the problem with the code,I do not want to use double pointer...This edited code gives output as 10->90->NULL..Why does not printing 30,50 and 70?What should I do for getting the right output?

Comment: @YTE1008 as I said restore the original code in the question and create a one more new question.