# How can I get the odd indexed nodes of a linked list in an another linked list?I do not want to use double pointer

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, singly-linked-list

I do not want to use double pointer in my code,please assume index of the first node as 1. I have a linked list 10->20->30->40->50->60->70->80->90->100->NULL In an another linked list whose head pointer is pLink,I want to copy the odd indexed nodes and get the output as 10->30->50->70->90->NULL.

```
    SLLI*OddNodes(SLLI*pHead)
{
    int counter =1;
    SLLI*pTemp=pHead;
    SLLI*pList=NULL;
    while(pTemp != NULL)
    {
        if(counter % 2 != 0)
        {
           if(pList==NULL)
           {
               pList=malloc(sizeof(SLLI));
               pList->data=pTemp->data;
               pList->next=NULL;
           }
           else
           {
               SLLI*pIter=pList;
               SLLI*pNew=malloc(sizeof(SLLI));
               pNew->data=pTemp->data;
               pNew->next=NULL;
               pIter->next=pNew;
               pIter=pIter->next;

           }
        }
        pTemp=pTemp->next;
        counter ++;
    }
    return pList;
}
```

When I run this code I get output as 10->90->NULL I know I have a problem with the "else" part. SLLI*pIter=pList does not make any sense, but what can I do for eliminating this mistake?

Comment: You asked the similar question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60165321/how-can-i-return-the-odd-indexed-nodes-of-a-singly-linked-list-in-a-new-singly-l

Comment: Yes but I edited the code and asked again...What is wrong with this?I am new on this platform as you see...

Comment: @ManojBanik Can you help me about the code?

Comment: That link has an accepted answer, probably you need to correct it here, "SLLI*OddNodes(SLLI*pHead)" it should be " SLLI* OddNodes(SLLI **pHead) ". See that answer.

Comment: @ManojBanik     Is not it possible to solve the problem without using DOUBLE POINTER?

Comment: What's wrong with double pointer? When you need a pointer of pointer, you have to use it. Study pointers, this is the only way to deal with it.

Comment: Nothing is wrong but I just wonder... Because I get 10->90->NULL as an output.But why can not get the rest? Where is 30-50-70??? I wonder this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I return the odd indexed nodes of a singly linked list in a new singly linked list ?Assume index of the first node as 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60165321/how-can-i-return-the-odd-indexed-nodes-of-a-singly-linked-list-in-a-new-singly-l)

Comment: @Fjodr it is also my question but edited my code and asked the same question again here...But this time more detailed... And find the answer that I want in this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/60172370/12877379.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is that `pList` is not changed at all in your `else` statement.

Wouldnt that do the trick:

```
SLLI*OddNodes(SLLI*pHead)
{
   int counter =1;
   SLLI*pTemp=pHead;
   SLLI*pList=NULL;
   SLLI*pNewHead=NULL;

   while(pTemp != NULL)
   {
      if(counter % 2 != 0)
      {
         if(pList==NULL)
         {
            pList=malloc(sizeof(SLLI));
            pList->data=pTemp->data;
            pList->next=NULL;
            pNewHead = pList;
         }
         else
         {
            pList->next = malloc(sizeof(SLLI));
            pList->next->data = pTemp->data;
            pList->next->next = NULL;
            pList = pList->next;
         } 
         pTemp = pTemp->next;
         counter++
      }
   }

   return pNewHead;
}
```

In addition I would check if `malloc` was succesful

Comment: When I edit my code as you write,I get only 90->NULL as output...

Comment: int main()
{
    SLLI*pHead=NULL;
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<11;i++)
    {
         pHead=AddItemtoEnd(pHead,i*10);
    }
   
    pHead=OddNodes(pHead);
    Printlist(pHead);
 This is my main by the way...
}

Comment: Well I see you want to return the head of new list, so we need so save that - I edit that

Comment: heeyyy you forgot put  "if(counter % 2 != 0)"... When you put this it is going to work exactly in the same way that I want...

Comment: Right, forgot that one and added it now

Answer (score 0):

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct SinglyLinkedListItem
{
    int data;
    struct SinglyLinkedListItem *next;
} SLLI;

SLLI * OddNodes( SLLI *pHead )
{
    int odd = 0;
    SLLI *pList = NULL;


    for ( SLLI *pCurrent = pList; pHead != NULL; pHead = pHead->next )
    {
        if ( odd ^= 1 )
        {
            if ( pCurrent == NULL )
            {
                pList = malloc( sizeof( SLLI ) );
                pList->data = pHead->data;
                pList->next = NULL;
                pCurrent = pList;
            }
            else
            {
                pCurrent->next = malloc( sizeof( SLLI ) );
                pCurrent->next->data = pHead->data;
                pCurrent->next->next = NULL;
                pCurrent = pCurrent->next;
            }
        }
    }

    return pList;
}
 int insert( SLLI **pHead, int data )
 {
    SLLI *pCurrent = malloc( sizeof( SLLI ) );
    int success = pCurrent != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        pCurrent->data = data;
        pCurrent->next = *pHead;
        *pHead = pCurrent;
    }

    return success;
 }

 void out( SLLI *pHead )
 {
    for ( ; pHead != NULL; pHead = pHead->next )
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", pHead->data );
    }

    puts( "null" );
 }

int main(void) 
{
    const int N = 10;

    SLLI *pHead = NULL;

    for ( int i = N; i != 0; --i )
    {
        insert( &pHead, 10 * i );
    }

    out( pHead );

    SLLI *pSecondHead = OddNodes( pHead );

    out( pHead );
    out( pSecondHead );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
10 -> 20 -> 30 -> 40 -> 50 -> 60 -> 70 -> 80 -> 90 -> 100 -> null
10 -> 20 -> 30 -> 40 -> 50 -> 60 -> 70 -> 80 -> 90 -> 100 -> null
10 -> 30 -> 50 -> 70 -> 90 -> null
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a DRY complement to [Vlad from Moscow's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60172772/3789665):

```
/**
 * Returns a list with the data from every other item starting at *original.
 * Does not modify the nodes from *original: malloc()s new nodes
 */
SLLI *OddNodes(SLLI const *original)
{
    int odd = 0;
    SLLI oddHead = { 0, NULL },
        *copy = &oddHead;

    for ( ; original != NULL ; original = original->next)
        if (odd ^= 1) {
            if (NULL == (copy->next = malloc(sizeof *copy)))
            /* alternatively, free "oddHead.next" & return NULL.
             * Should be documented in head comment! */
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            copy = copy->next;
            copy->data = original->data;
            copy->next = NULL;
        }

    return oddHead.next;
}
```